# App is crashing while using Google map in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using Fragments for my application for the very first time. I have implemented Google Map in one of the fragments, Whenever I select the tab having map it loads that successfully but once I go to the main menu in some other activity it crashes I don't know why.

Here is my crash log :-

```
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {MyFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3444)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3462)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:149)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1361)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at com.fragments.FindMyCar.onDestroyView(FindMyCar.java:297)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1705)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:996)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1921)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:335)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5184)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1111)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3431)
03-28 14:14:23.175: E/AndroidRuntime(18215):    ... 11 more
```

Inside my fragment I have implemented like this :-

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.findmycar, null);

        initViews(view);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());


        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            fm = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            map = fm.getMap();

            if(map == null){

                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "null", 0).show();
            }
            else{

                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                // checking for the best provider and connectivity

                // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                if (netInfo !=null && netInfo.isConnected()) {


                    if(isGpsEnable()){


                        provider=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                        mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(mLocation==null){
                            //onLocationChanged(location);

                            provider=LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                            mLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            Log.d("Location","Location " + mLocation + " " + provider);

                            if(mLocation!=null){

                                onLocationChanged(mLocation);
                            }
                            else{

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch your current location at the moment. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }else {
                            onLocationChanged(mLocation);
                        }

                    }
                    else{

                        showGpsAlert();
                    }

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            }
        }


@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        if(fragment!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "inif", 0).show();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else{


        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        }
    }
```

Its perfectly running while destroying the reference in onDestroyView() method but after that app crashes, don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this and let me know put following code into `onDestroyView()`

```
try{
          SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
          FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
```

Comment: Where should I put this code, in my onDestroyView() only ??

Comment: Just a crisp :), thank you so much for this but can u just explain it a bit, it would be great :)

Comment: it's becoz you are try to destroy  `Fragment fragment` instead of  `SupportMapFragment fragment`